# Hooks and test project are in different project but in same solution

Tags: c#, hook, specflow

I am using specflow for API automation.
I want to know that if hooks is in different project and your tests is in different project then how can test project refer hooks so that code work properly. i already added the reference of other project but in case of hooks it is failing..
Please suggest the solution
Language :C#

Please note that When hooks and test project is in same project then it works fine

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you're looking for here is the guidance on using Bindings from External Assemblies.

Here's the documentation on the SpecFlow site: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Use-Bindings-from-External-Assemblies.html

To summarize:

- Your test project has to reference the hooks project so that it'll be copied to the output directory along with your project
- You need to include a reference to the assembly in a `specflow.json` or `app.config` file within your specflow project.

Example of `specflow.json`:

```json
{
  "stepAssemblies": [
    {
      "assembly": "MySharedBindings"
    }
  ]
}
```